# Gridlayout pictures to small eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, imagebutton, grid-layout

I have a gridLayout form 3 by 3. with in there imagebuttons.
the grid is working, but i want the images to fill the weight of the parent.
this is the code i have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tict.MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mygrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"  />
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </GridLayout>
```

I want to keep the gridLayout if that is posible.

EDIT: I want 3 image buttons at the top row. All 3 being 1/3 weight of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could't find a solution, so made a nested LiniarLayout.
Part of the new code is now:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/TG" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `layout_width` and `layout_height` properties with

`wrap_content` : , **which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding)**

change to:

`match_parent` : **which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)**

Comment: I have done that but than I get 1 image button that filling the parent. But I want the first 3 to fill the parent . so all 3 1/3 of parent .  than the next 3 on the second row. Doing the same.